TypeError: 'async_generator' object is not iterable. Trying to run pyrogram code
I was trying to run pyrogram script that gets chat's history and write it to txt file.
def on_button_pressed(self, event: Button.Pressed) -> None:
    app = Client("TeleCLI", os.getenv("API_ID"), os.getenv("API_HASH"))
        with open("text.txt", "a", encoding="utf-8") as file:
            file.write(list(app.get_chat_history("971977254", limit=20)))

But it is giving me this error:
TypeError: 'async_generator' object is not iterable
I tried to run this in another python file and it surprisingly worked perfectly:
def main(user_id, limit):
    app = Client("TeleCLI", os.getenv("API_ID"), os.getenv("API_HASH"))
    content = []

    app.start()

    mess = app.get_chat_history(user_id, limit=limit)

    for message in mess:
        content.append(message)

    app.stop()

    return content

I wanted to use client.get_chat_history to get all the data i needed, but to use this method I needed to use asynchronous function and when i run the function i get the error that the function was never awaited.
